# Trouble enabling CORS

Tags: token, assets

I'm having EXTREME difficulty enabling CORS for my .toml file. I've set the home domain of the asset issuing wallet. I do not know where to put the code for enabling CORS, and there is no mention of this in the tutorial. Do I create a new file? What is this file called? I only know html and some javascript.

I would love to complete this asset creation experiment with the stellar.toml tutorial.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is general question about configuring web-server/proxy to send CORS headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Apache webserver

Create a `.htaccess` file in the `{your_website_root}/.well-known/` directory.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

And reload Apache server with `apachectl -k graceful` command.

#### Nginx

Open your config file (usually `/etc/nginx/conf.d/{your_domain}.conf`), add the following lines into the `server` directive:

```
location /.well-known {
   allow all;
   if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
     add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
     return 204;
   }
   if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, OPTIONS';       
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
   }
}
```

Reload Nginx configuration: `nginx -s reload`.

#### IIS 7

Create a `web.config` file in the `{your_website_root}/.well-known/` directory with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
     <customHeaders>
       <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
     </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

There is no need to restart a web-server, all changes in `web.config` automatically reload corresponding `application domain`.

#### Using different web-server?

Visit [enable-cors.org](https://enable-cors.org/server.html), locate your web-server in the list and configure it accordingly to the above recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling CORS will depend on your server environment.

You need to configure your server to return the header: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

So in .Net core it’s done with middleware:

`services.AddCors().AllowAnyOrigin();`

In a Linux environment I believe you can use a `.htaccess` file with something like:

`Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Hope that points you in the right direction.